# match plot color with ticks color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a plot with bars, including twin axis.

I want the ticks have exactly the same color as the bars, that means, including the parameter "alpha".

However I cannot give them this paramenter.

Any solution?

Here a piece of relevant code:

```
# Drawing the bar plot:

rects1 = ax1.bar(x_axis, y_values, bar_width, color='magenta', alpha = 0.4)

# Playing with color for the bars

ax1.set_ylabel('Charge value [nC]', color='magenta', alpha = 0.4)

# Get the ticks and copy color HERE DOES NOT WORK

for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
 tl.set_color(color='magenta', alpha = 0.4)
```

The traceback:

```
tl.set_color(color='magenta', alpha = 0.4)
TypeError: set_color() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alpha'
```

Comment: I don't use matplotlib but it may not support transparent labels. If you can pass any color with the `color` argument, then pass it the resulting color from applying alpha 0.4 to magenta (hint: you may take a screenshot and pick the color of the bar); a better solution would be to not use alpha at all.. if the background color is plain and does not change, you do not need alpha at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_color`, as the name indicates, only sets the color. To set the alpha level use `set_alpha`:

```
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('magenta')
    tl.set_alpha(0.4)
```